# Error when linking my account to biology.stackexchange.com beta

Tags: support, linked-accounts

Sorry if this is not the correct meta forum for this, but I am unable to ask this in the biology meta because there seems to have been an error when linking (I have no rep and so cannot ask any questions on its meta).   I went to http://biology.stackexchange.com and tried to login.  Every single other time I've ever done this for  a stackexchange site, I clicked on "Google" and it signed me in and linked my account with no problem.

However, for this site, it took a very long time and when it finally came back, it looks like it gave me a bizzarre vanilla account:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/198/user198

Not sure what's going on, but it didn't copy over my profile information (or even my name!), nor did it give me the usual 100 rep, so I am unable to participate on this site in any meaningful way.  I'm not sure it's related, but I also never received the welcome email that this site went to beta, despite the fact that I was committed.

I believe my biology account is simply corrupted at this point.  Can someone investigate this?

Comment: Curiously, the account you mention is linked to your account here, so it should have awarded the 100 rep.

Comment: The same thing happened to me when I tried to create an [account on Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/5548/jukka-suomela).

Comment: I deleted my account, created a [new one](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/5574/jukka-suomela), and it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reproduced [on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/199/jeremy-banks); the accounts were associated properly but I didn't get the association bonus. However, I then created [an account on Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/161/jeremy-banks) and though it didn't get it either, I was granted the association bonus on Biology after I created the account on Chinese.

It seems like the association bonus check is being run when the new account is added, but the new account is being excluded for some reason.

*edit:* When I created an account on Poker.SE it associated properly. Both it and my account on Chinese.SE are now at the expected 101 reputation. I guess the issue is resolved.

Comment: As Jukka mentioned in comments, deleting and re-creating solved the problem for me.  Thanks for your elaboration as well.